# Determine if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}$ converges on $\mathbb{R}$. Proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> Determine if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}$ converges on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt:**

Examining the behavior of $\frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}$, we see that:

$$\|\frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \infty}\Bigg|\frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}\Bigg| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

If we let $M_{n} = \frac{1}{n^2}$ it has been established that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges. So by application of the M- test, our series converges.

**My problem:** I always have trouble deciding how to bound things in this form: $$\Bigg|\frac{1}{x^{2} + n^{2}}\Bigg| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$ as an example. What am I allowed to remove and what can I not remove from any sort of comparison? If my $x$ is being assumed as fixed am I allowed to remove that to bound my function or is it the $n$ that I can remove if need be?   I may have answered my own question by stating that $x$ is fixed so that means any $n$ term would have to remain... But in a similar question my professor did a comparison of $k(k + x^2) \geq k$ to manipulate denominators. So again it comes down to what am I allowed to remove?

Comment: @JMoravitz Done. Thanks for the input

Comment: Reading your question... it appears that you are just needing a reminder that for $a,b>0$ you have $a\leq b\iff \frac{1}{b}\leq\frac{1}{a}$.  Similarly, for $c\geq 1$ you have $ac\geq a$.

Comment: I agree that at its root it is probably that inequality, but I think there is more that I'm not fully getting. Because if it just a matter of simply removing anything then I should be able to remove any denominators to get a convergent series.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+n^2}$ is going to be less than $\frac{1}{n}$ and the sum $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is unbounded... but that doesn't mean that $\sum\frac{1}{n+n^2}$ is going to be unbounded... it is *at most* unbounded, but as we learn by more careful bounding that it will indeed converge.  If you are wanting to remove things from the denominator, generally you can phrase things correctly so as to remove anything except the highest ordered term.

Comment: You try to show a sum of positive terms is bounded above by a sum which converges to a finite number to show it too must converge, or you show a sum of positive terms is bounded below by a sum of positive terms which we know to diverge to show the original sum diverges as well.  What you "remove" will depend on which direction you want the inequality sign to be.  Be mindful that if negative numbers are involved, the phrasing must be done *carefully* since it may not be a direct comparison but rather a limit comparison being used.

Comment: This provides some clarity. As in your example $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is a bound, but so is $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ ( a better bound), and we keep the highest order term. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in\Bbb R$, we have $x^2 \geq 0$. Hence, $x^2+n^2 \geq n^2$ and thus (by taking the reciprocal*) $$\frac1{x^2+n^2} \le \frac1{n^2}.$$

* For two strictly positive real numbers $r_1, r_2$, we have $$r_1\geq r_2 \iff \frac1{r_1} \le \frac1{r_2}.$$

Comment: So it is a matter of remembering what set I am working with and noting what could happen with either variable. So $x$ is "fixed", while I vary $n$, but we observe the behavior will remain the same so we can draw our conclusions.

Comment: @dc3rd Right: You fix $x$ because you want to prove something for all real $x$, and you vary $n$ because this is the variable you are summing over.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the series is running on $n$ therefore everything that is not a function of n is a constant.

Secondly, to "bound"  these functions keep the following in mind.

$$\forall \space x,y\in \mathbf{R^+}$$
If $$ \space x>y$$
Then
$$\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{y}$$

Now since both $x^2$ and $n^2$ are positive quantities
And $$ x^2 +n^2 \geq n^2$$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{x^2+n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$\implies \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+n^2} \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$
By comparision test i.e. If the Larger series converges then the smaller one converges too.

The given series is convergent.

Comment: If $x>y$ then $1/x < 1/y$??? Consider $x=1$, $y=-1$.

Comment: my bad, I meant R^+